# How can I create user in Jboss 6.1?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

I'd like to create an user for remote EJB client connection in JBoss 6.1.

I read some tutorials, and they are about to I should use add-user.sh.

But add-user.sh is in JBoss 7, but it isn't in Jboss 6.1

In JBoss 6.1 how can I create new user for remote EJB clienting?

Comment: Jboss EAP 6.1.0 or JBoss AS 6.1.0.Final?